# xargs string used as an input for agrep

Tags: grep, xargs, zcat, agrep

Guys I am using xargs to pass the input for a agrep.I am using xargs like the below

```
Script:    
xargs -L 1 -I string echo "RequestId="string | xargs -L 1 -I string zcat FILEB | agrep -dEOE string


Output till "RequestId="string
RequestID=543214324
RequestID=512121221
RequestID=521212121
```

My goal is to agrep this Request ID's in another file "File B". Since this file is zipped I need to use zcat before doing agrep...But if I do this I am getting incorrect results.. The final "string" which I use in agrep is not proper.. Any suggestions regarding this would be highly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It is not completely clear what you want. I assume you have a file FILEA containing:

```
543214324
512121221
521212121
```

and that you want to agrep FILEB.gz for:

```
RequestID=543214324
RequestID=512121221
RequestID=521212121
```

FILEBB.gz is gzipped so you need `zcat` to decompress it, and you cannot use zgrep because you depend on a feature only found in `agrep`.

Using GNU Parallel you can do:

```
cat FILEA | parallel zcat FILEB.gz \| agrep -dEOE RequestID={}
```

One of the advantages of doing it in parallel is that if FILEB.gz is too big to fit in memory, then this will make sure to search in parallel thus avoiding reading FILEB.gz from disk for each search. Another advantage is that you can use multiple CPU cores which your computer is almost guaranteed to have these days.

You can install GNU Parallel simply by:

```
wget http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/plain/src/parallel
chmod 755 parallel
cp parallel sem
```

Watch the intro videos for GNU Parallel to learn more: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1